# Git: update master branch from two branches

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge

Me and my friend are working on a project simultaneously so I have created 2 branches `branch_a` (I work on it) `branch_b` (he works on it) and now we want to merge his work with mine in the `master` branch.
What I do usually when I complete my work is:

```
git add *
git commit -m "my new commit"
git push origin branch_a
```

After that I simply merge my work into the master branch like this:

```
git checkout master
git merge branch_a
git push origin master
```

But when I want to get the work of my friend in `branch_b` by doing this:

```
git checkout branch_a
git merge branch_b
```

I get this message **`Already up-to-date`**!!
How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation here is that your local `branch_b` does not have the latest changes/work which your collaborator has pushed to the remote repository.  Perhaps the quickest fix would be to just `git fetch` and then merge `branch_a` with the remote tracking branch for `branch_b`:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout branch_a
get merge origin/branch_b
```

Or, if you also want to update the local `branch_b` as well, you could `git pull` on that branch, and then do the merge with `branch_b`:

```
git checkout branch_b
git pull origin branch_b
git checkout branch_a
git merge branch_b
```

Comment: and what `git fetch` does ?

Comment: `git fetch` updates the remote tracking branches, e.g. `origin/branch_b`, but does not affect any local branches.  Doing a `git pull` on a branch is equivalent to doing a `git fetch` followed by a merge or rebase of the tracking branch into the local branch.